# How to simplify multiple if else conditions in JavaScript - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how to reduce this condition logic in a simpler way. if the status values increase the conditions go on and on, please help to write a clean code

```
const getColor = status => {
    if (status === 'positive') {
      return { backgroundColor: 'red' }
    } else if (status === 'negative') {
      return { backgroundColor: 'orange' }
    } else if (status === 'neutral') {
      return { backgroundColor: 'blue' }
    }else if (status === 'none') {
      return { backgroundColor: 'white' }
    }else if (status === 'all') {
      return { backgroundColor: 'black' }
    }
  }

     <p style={getColor(result.sentiment_label)}>test</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

For your usecase, you can use switch :

```
switch (status) {
  case 'positive':
    return { backgroundColor: 'red' }
  case 'negative':
    return { backgroundColor: 'orange' }
  ...
  default:
    return { backgroundColor: 'black' }
}
```

Another solution, which is shorter (but can be harder to read) can be :

```
const statusBgColorMap = {
  positive: 'red',
  negative: 'orange',
  ...
}

return { backgroundColor: statusBgColorMap[status] || 'defaultcolor' }
```

Comment: **the second** way is very cleaner _thanks_!

Answer (score 1):

Use object instead:

```
const COLORS = {
  positive: "red",
  negative: "orange",
  neutrla: "blue",
  none: "white",
  all: "black",
}

<p style={{ backgroundColor: COLORS[result.sentiment_label] }}>
  test
</p>
```

Comment: wow, this way is working fine for my requirement _thanks wscourge_

Comment: You're welcome. You can store the `COLORS` variable outside of your component, too, so it does not get redefined on every render.

Answer (score 0):

switch statement maybe? Itll certainly read much nicer:

```
    const getColor = status => {
      switch(status) {
        case 'positive':
          return 'red';
        break;
        case ''negative:
          return 'orange'
        break;
        case ''neutral:
          return 'blue'
        break;
       case ''none:
          return 'white'
        break;
      default:
        return 'black'
     }
    }
    
  <p style={{backgroundColor: getColor(result.sentiment_label) }}>test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be the following:

```
const getColor = status => {
        if (status === 'positive') return { backgroundColor: 'red' }
        if (status === 'negative') return { backgroundColor: 'orange'}
        if (status === 'neutral') return { backgroundColor: 'blue' }
        if (status === 'none') return { backgroundColor: 'white' }
        if (status === 'all') return { backgroundColor: 'black' }
        return null
      }
```

Considering that you return inside the if statement next conditions won't run, thus you don't need else if. Furthermore you can remove curly brackets considering that you only have one command per if statement

Comment: ok, some clear way _thanks_